# ¿Como manejar u obtener el código de error en la auto-configuración de las bases de datos de spring boot?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

tengo un servicio web en spring boot, el cual tengo especificado en el archivo de properties las propiedades necesarias para que al correr el servicio web  como spring boot app se conecte automáticamente a las bases de datos que necesito.

Mi duda mas que nada es si se puede manejar u obtener el código de error o la Exception que arrojaría spring al intentar conectarse automáticamente a las BDs y estas no se encuentren o estén caídas o no se pueda acceder ya sea por que esta mal la ip, el usuario o la contraseña, ect.

muchas gracias espero sus respuestas :)

Comment: Solo para entender mejor tu proposito, con que fin quisieras saber esta excepcion? Normalmente, al no poder conectarse a la BD, la aplicacion falla y no termina de inicializarse. Creo que no es posible atrapar la excepcion y manejarla,a menos que crees la conexion a la BD desde casi cero por tu propia cuenta.

Comment: @cavpollo prácticamente es para poder mandar a un log si se estableció la conexión correctamente o si fallo, porque fallo, por que esta mal la url o el usuario o la contraseña, si eso es lo que estoy haciendo ahorita creando la conexión manualmente, nmas que estoy cambiando todos los métodos que tengo a la nueva forma, gracias por tu comentario